# JQUERY auto complete on a text function that takes input from other text in html form

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Hi I want to read a text value from one input field , and then use it within a JQUERY function to get data from Database
I want the source to be populated like this : /search/batch_name_by_barnID/1
but output is like : /batch_name_by_barnID?term=1

How can I set the this part : source: "/search/batch_name_by_barnID/"+$('#barn_id').text(),
to get output like  /search/batch_name_by_barnID/{number}
instead of /search/batch_name_by_barnID?term=1

My HTML is :

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control search_occupied_barn_name" placeholder="Type here ..." name="barn_name">
      <span class="help-block search_occupied_barn_name_empty" style="display: none;">No Results Found ...</span>
      <input type="text" class="search_barn_id" name="barn_id" id="barn_id">
      <label>باتش</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control search_batch_name_barn" placeholder="Type here ..." name="BatchName">
      <span class="help-block search_batch_name_barn_empty" style="display: none;">No Results Found ...</span>
      <input type="text" class="search_batch_id" name="batch_id" id="batch_id">
```

my JQUERY is :

```
 $( ".search_batch_name_barn" ).autocomplete({
       source: "/search/batch_name_by_barnID/"+$('#barn_id').text(),
       minLength: 1,
       response: function(event, ui) {
             if (ui.content.length === 0) {

                 $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
                 $(this).next().removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
                 $(".search_batch_name_barn_empty").show();
                 $('.form_submit').hide();

             } else {
                 $(".search_batch_name_barn_empty").hide();
                 $('.form_submit').show();
             }
         },
       select: function(event, ui) {
         $('.search_batch_id').val(ui.item.id);
         $('.search_batch_name_barn').val(ui.item.value);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is : I added a button then fired the autocomplete for the "search_batch_name_barn" from the button using the search method
code :
default.js

```
  $("#getBatch").click(function () {
     alert("test");
     $(".search_batch_name_barn").show();
     $(".search_batch_name_barn").autocomplete('search');
  });
```

HTML

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control search_occupied_barn_name" placeholder="Type here ..." name="barn_name">
      <span class="help-block search_occupied_barn_name_empty" style="display: none;">No Results Found ...</span>
      <input type="hidden" class="search_barn_id" name="barn_id" id="barn_idorg">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name ="getBatch" id="getBatch">Get Batch</button>
      <label>باتش</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control search_batch_name_barn" placeholder="Type here ..." name="BatchName">
      <span class="help-block search_batch_name_barn_empty" style="display: none;">No Results Found ...</span>
      <input type="hidden" class="search_batch_id" name="batch_id" id="batch_id">
```